# Elastic Beanstalk website does not load on Firefox

Tags: amazon-web-services, firefox, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I am hosting this [open source website](https://github.com/xinthose/personal_website) running on this domain: [www.xinthose.com](http://www.xinthose.com).  The website loads on Google Chrome, but not Firefox (no error message).  The Elastic Beanstalk URL does load though: http://xinthose2-env.eba-4qavumcw.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/home.  Can anyone help me to understand this please?  Here is my `browserslist`:

```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
not IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```

AWS EC2 automatically runs the website with [`node server.js`](https://github.com/xinthose/personal_website/blob/master/src/server.js)

```
"use strict";
const express = require("express");
const compression = require('compression');

// config
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app_folder = "./";
const options = {
  dotfiles: 'ignore',
  etag: false,
  extensions: ['html', 'js', 'scss', 'css'],
  index: false,
  maxAge: '1y',
  redirect: true,
}

// create app
const app = express();
app.use(compression());
app.use(express.static(app_folder, options));

// serve angular paths
app.all('*', function (req, res) {
    res.status(200).sendFile(`/`, {root: app_folder});
});

// start listening
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("Node Express server for " + app.name + " listening on http://localhost:" + port);
});
```

My Firefox is up to date: version 80.0.1 (64 bit).  Is Firefox more strict on JavaScript use?  Do I need to change something in `server.js`?

Beanstalk setup:

[image]

Comment: Seems to work now, but only `http://xinthose.com`, not `http://www.xinthose.com`

Comment: @Marcin yes, you're right; I have to use a private window each time to test it; weird; there must be something different between Chrome and Firefox with URL handling; the application is angular, so it should work on both

Comment: Do you have your domain set for www as well? For example, in route53 make A Alias record to apex domain from www.

Comment: @Marcin yup, that was it!  Thank you.  If you post that as the answer, I will accept it.  I only had an A record for xinthose.com, not www.xinthose.com.  Apparently Chrome can handle the redirect but not Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by **missing** A Alias record for `www.xinthose.com`.

The **solution** was to add it, so that `www.xinthose.com` so that it points to EB domain in Route53.

Comment: Yes, I actually made `www.xinthose.com` point to the Beanstalk URL: `xinthose2-env.eba-4qavumcw.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com`